# Directory not found from Makefile

Tags: python, makefile

I'm trying to setup a few scripts in a Makefile for a Python project. My current Makefile looks like this:

```
install:
    pip install -r requirements.txt
activate:
    source env/bin/activate
deactivate:
    deactivate
jupyter:
    jupyter lab
```

This file is in the project's root folder. The env folder exists and has all the content you'd expect from a virtual environment. Now from the root folder, when I type `make activate`, I have the following error:

```
source env/bin/activate
make: source: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:4: activate] Error 127
```

But if I type `source env/bin/activate` directly in a terminal, it works as expected. What is the issue here?

Thank you.

Comment: `source` is not a standalone command.  It is internal to `bash`.  The problem here is that makefile targets get executed in a separate shell that exists only as long as that command runs, so the environment variable changes immediately go away.  Put shortly, you simply can't do this with a Makefile.

Comment: Makes sense, thank. What would be the common way to achieve this then?

Comment: You can use shell aliases, but honestly, why is "make deactivate" better than just typing "deactivate"?  I think you're just on the wrong path here.  Get used to `. env/bin/activate`.  Personally, I find virtual environments counterproductive and never use them.

Comment: The immediate problem is that `source` is a bash operation, and make doesn't invoke bash, it invokes `/bin/sh` POSIX shell (by default) and `source` is not a POSIX standard command.  If you use the `.` command instead, which IS a POSIX standard command, you would not see any error.  However, as @TimRoberts says, the way these virtual env commands work is they modify the shell's environment and there's no way a program (like make, or any other program) can ever modify the environment of the program (shell) that invoked it.  That's why `source` (and `.`) are shell built-ins.